# composer to install a package or module in a custom path?

Tags: php, module, drupal-8

I have tried to install a Drupal module with the composer in a specific path,

I check these links but I can't figure out that.

Please check this and tell me what is wrong and what I should do?

What do I want?

> Install the Signature field module in the `modules/patched` directory.

this is part of my `composer.json` file that is related to this issue.

```
"require": {
    "composer/installers": "^1.0.24",
    "drupal/signature_field": "^1.0@RC",
},

    "installer-paths": {
        "core": ["type:drupal-core"],
        "modules/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-module"],
        "profiles/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-profile"],
        "themes/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-theme"],
        "drush/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-drush"],
        "modules/custom/{$name}": ["type:drupal-custom-module"],
        "themes/custom/{$name}": ["type:drupal-custom-theme"],
        "modules/patched/{$name}": ["type:drupal-patched-module"]
    },
    "patches": {
        "drupal/signature_field": {
            "Drupal Signature Field fix multi feilds": "modules/patched/signature_field/signature_field-2993223-08.patch"     
        }
    }
},
```

At the end I do `composer install` and `composer update`, but the module doesn't transfer to the folder that I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there we should define the custom path and defining that which module or package should install in that path.

like this

```
"installer-paths": {

    // custom path with the list of items that should installed there.

    "modules/patched/{$name}": [
        "drupal/signature_field",
        "drupal/eck",
        "drupal/auto_entitylabel"
    ],
}
```

The package or module should be in your require section as well.

```
"require": {
        "composer/installers": "^1.0.24",
        "drupal/auto_entitylabel": "2.x-dev",
        "drupal/signature_field": "^1.0@RC",
        "drupal/eck": "^1.0@alpha",
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could help (note about `extra`):

```
{
    "extra": {
        "installer-paths": {
            "modules/patched/{$name}": ["drupal/signature_field"],
            "modules/patched/{$name}": ["another/package"]
        }
    }
}
```

[Reference](https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/how-do-i-install-a-package-to-a-custom-path-for-my-framework.md), [GitHub comment](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1948#issuecomment-37122919)

Probably, this'd work:

```
{
    "extra": {
        "installer-paths": {
            "modules/patched/{$name}": ["drupal/signature_field"]
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "installer-paths": {
            "modules/patched/{$name}": ["drupal/another_module"]
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
{
    "extra": {
        "installer-paths": {
            "modules/patched/{$name}": ["drupal/signature_field"]
        },
        "installer-paths": {
            "modules/patched/{$name}": ["drupal/another_module"]
        }
    }
}
```

Also,

> You cannot use this to change the path of any package. This is only
>   applicable to packages that require composer/installers and use a
>   custom type that it handles.

You can also [group](https://github.com/composer/installers#custom-install-paths) your packages by `type`:

```
{
    "extra": {
        "installer-paths": {
            "your/custom/path/{$name}/": ["type:wordpress-plugin"]
        }
    }
}
```

or certain `vendor`:

```
{
    "extra": {
        "installer-paths": {
            "your/custom/path/{$name}/": ["vendor:drupal"]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It works, but what about when I have a couple of module with this case, how should I add?

Comment: You mean, you want to add more than one module to the same path?

Comment: in this case, just the first one will be applied by composer any other in the next will ignored, in this case just the signature field

Comment: Have you tried to create separate `extra` fields for each package you need to install in certain directory?

Comment: that is wrong that I add one extra for each package, maybe there being 100 packages that it should add at least 200 extra lines of code.

Comment: Try to put all in `installer-paths`, or group by vendor.

Comment: is this an array right? `["drupal/signature_field"]` then what about making that larger

Comment: You could take a look at the docs I mentioned. I can't tell you exactly if that works, because I don't have your environment.

Comment: thanks, I figure out that and find the complete solution. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55808475/9246297